# Find an infinite set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

$X$ is the union of the intervals $[\frac{1}{n^2},2-\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}]$  for $n=1$ to infinity. Find $X$.

My question is about the first few intervals in the union. When $n=1$, the interval is [1,-1]. Is this the same as [-1,1] or is it an empty interval?
My gut feeling is that it is an empty interval which would make the final answer the open interval $X=(0,2)$. Is this right?

Comment: I would guess $[1,-1]$ is empty.  But probably the question is poorly formulated.

Comment: By definition $[1,-1]=\{x\in\Bbb R:1\le x\le -1\}$, which is clearly empty. But it would have been better to start $n$ at $3$ to avoid any question.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the answer is $(0,2)$. To prove this you need to show that indeed any point in $(0,2)$ is a point in one of these intervals; and vice versa every point in any one of the intervals is a point in $(0,2)$.

The second part is easy, the first part requires you to show that give $x\in(0,2)$ we can find some $n$ such that $\frac1{n^2}\leq x$ and $x\leq2-\frac3{\sqrt n}$.